# Thinkpad X1 Carbon won't suspend after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: laptop, power-management, suspend, thinkpad

I upgraded to 13.10 and have since had problems with suspend when I close the laptop lid.   Prior to the upgrade, if you closed the lid it suspended the computer and all was well.

After the upgrade closing the lid will result in the battery discharging (if not plugged in) and an aggravated user!

Running Ubuntu for years, but a little newbie on the power stuff.

Comment: What power settings do you have? Search for Power in the dash.

Comment: Hi Luis- -   I have it set as "when lid is closed, suspend"

Comment: Try to suspend manually: sudo pm-suspend; and then if it works check if it resumes without problems. If it goes wrong please add to your answer the contents of /var/log/pm-suspend.log.

Comment: While I don't know how to resolve your issue, I have an X1 Carbon running 13.10 and no issues with suspending on lid close. We can compare our settings, only I'm not sure where to look

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I am having the same or similar problem, so I tried your advice and it still failed. Strangely, I don't see anything failing in my pm-suspend.log: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6949993/

Answer (score 0):

I am in the middle of working through some issues that sound similar. I was able to resolve most of them by changing the USB settings in the bios.

change:

- Always On USB to disable
- USB 3.0 mode to enable

I do not have an X1 Carbon in front of me, but the bios options should be under the 'config' tab then under the USB section. The settings are on my T530 and an X230 I have access too.

Answer (score 0):

When searching for solutions to this problem, I came across this thread discussing the suspend issue with X1 Carbon and Ubuntu 13.10. Since it changed from 13.04 to 13.10 I a little bit sceptical about this, but a user (a Lenovo employee) says a fix will be included in [BIOS update 1.13](http://linux-thinkpad.10952.n7.nabble.com/Gen-2-Haswell-X1-Carbon-suspend-to-RAM-hang-td21039.html).

Comment: According to the mentioned thread on the Thinkpad forum, BIOS v 1.13 is released, and it fixes the suspend issue [link to thread](http://linux-thinkpad.10952.n7.nabble.com/Gen-2-Haswell-X1-Carbon-suspend-to-RAM-hang-td21039.html#a21117) This is explicitly mention in the accompanying [readme.txt](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/gruj08uc.txt)